# How to stop UML Lab from greying out private variables in class diagram?

Tags: java, uml

I'm trying to generate a class diagram (reverse engineering from source), using Eclipse (on OS X) and UML Lab, and for some reason some of the variables are greyed out. Here's an example:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykrmc.png

However, there are classes that have all variables greyed out. I do not see any pattern, some are initiated when declared, some are not. All of them are used. It is hard to read the names when the whole list is greyed out, especially when I copy the image into a Word document.

I have checked Preferences, played with some settings, but nothing has changed. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UML Lab uses Grey color to mark "legacy" styled elements. "Legacy" refers to the template set (or CodeStyle) used to generate/import the code for these elements. This option is defined in the Profile containing the "Legacy" CodeStyle/Stereotype. I'm not sure if you can easily edit that. But you can get rid of all such highlighting if you switch off automatic Constraint Validation (right in the UML Lab main preferences) and reopen the diagram.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the example image I would say it greys out only private variables (marked with "-").
Have you checked settings on color depending on the visibility of the variable?

Comment: I have. I even removed all marking styles but it still doesn't help. Thanks though.